# PowerPoint - Consolidate internal Excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, links, diagrams

A PowerPoint presentation features a lot of diagrams.
All those diagrams are copied via embedding (not linking) to the PowerPoint file.

Is it possible to reconnect all those "internal" Excel sheets, so that updating values in one of the diagrams (via Right Click -> Edit Data) also updates the value for the "internal" sheets of all the other diagrams?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Each time you embed something from Excel into PPT, the entire Excel workbook gets embedded and the different embedded workbooks have no connection to one another. If you link instead of embed, then you'd get what you're asking for (but would need to be careful not to break the links)

Comment: You can try to create these sheets in Excel and create connection between PowerPoint and Excel.